Xdebug doesn't conect on cli application using docker
Xdebug is working on web applications without problems but not on CLI , I think its a problem with the host.
I have this on php.ini
[xdebug]
xdebug.mode=develop,debug
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.log_level=1
xdebug.log=/dev/null

and this on docker-compose.yml
  php-fpm:
    build: phpdocker/php-fpm
    container_name: mycontainer-php-fpm
    working_dir: /application
    environment:
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: "remote_host=host.docker.internal"
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=mylocalserver.test"
      PHP_EXTENSION_XDEBUG: "1"
      XDEBUG_SESSION: "1"

this configuration is correct for web but not for CLI, I tried all the combinations that I have found on Internet but is still not working

Which PHP and XDebug version are you using?

php 7.4 and xdebug 3

Are you sure about PHP with 7.4? Because XDebug 3 requires PHP 8. Which exact version of XDebug are you using?

I'm using php 8 , 7.4 its usedon another project
